# How to separate xaml markup into different file in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a very big xaml markup in MainPage.xaml. More I add more it becomes a mess. Can I split my xaml markup into different files or store it in a ResourceDictionary and load it into MainPage.xaml?

Answer (score 0):

Not known to me. What I do is, for example, deposit the sytling of my controls in the App.xaml. For example, for a TextBlock element:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="CalibriLight"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

In Mainpage.xaml I grab it so:

```
<TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle1}"/>
```

Thus, you save a lot of time while styling and your Mainpage.xaml is much tidier.

Comment: Maybe it is better you recall those resources as “ThemeResource” and not “DynamicResource”, in order to keep save all the different values for the Light/Dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can create a ResourceDictionary and put your style in it.Then use MergedDictionaries to load it into MainPage.For more information you can view this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references).

in ResourceDirectionary(e.g. named Styles.xaml):

```
<ResourceDictionary.....>
  <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
  ...
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

in MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>​
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>​
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>​
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>​
​
        </ResourceDictionary>​
    </Page.Resources>

......
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}">
```